# Problem with conditional woocommerce custom checkout field

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

Please help!! I need one of my woocommerce checkout fields to display only on the condition that product x (product 179, as you'll see below) is **not** in the user's cart. As it is, I can get this to work properly using the default woocommerce fields (derived from [billing],[shipping],[account], and [order]... but I need this to work for a custom checkout field that I created as shown here:

```
/**
* Add the field to the checkout (the script)
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'the_script' );

function the_script( $checkout ) {

echo '<div id="the_script"><h2>' . __('') . '</h2>';

woocommerce_form_field( 'user_script', array(
    'type'          => 'textarea',
    'class'         => array('extracheckoutinfo form-row-wide'),
    'label'         => __('What is the script?'),
    'placeholder'   => __('You can skip this section if you added the "Create the Script" extra to your purchase'),
    'required'      => true
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'user_script' ));

echo '</div>';

}



/**
* Process the checkout (the script)
*/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'the_script_field_process');

function the_script_field_process() {
// Check if set, if its not set add an error.
if ( ! $_POST['user_script'] )
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Provide<strong>the script you want to use.</strong>' ), 'error' );
 }

 /**
 * Update the order meta with field value (the script)
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',     'the_script_field_update_order_meta' );

 function call_script_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
if ( ! empty( $_POST['user_script'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'The Script', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['user_script'] ) );
}
}



/**
* Display field value on the order edit page (the  script)
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'the_script_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function the_script_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
echo '<p><strong>'.__('The Script').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'The Script', true ) . '</p>';
}



/**
* Check if a specific product ID is in the cart
*/
function wc_ninja_product_is_in_the_cart() {
// Add your special product IDs here
$ids = array( '179' );;

// Products currently in the cart
$cart_ids = array();

// Find each product in the cart and add it to the $cart_ids array
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $cart_product = $values['data'];
    $cart_ids[]   = $cart_product->id;
}

// If one of the special products are in the cart, return true.
if ( ! empty( array_intersect( $ids, $cart_ids ) ) ) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}


/**
* Conditionally remove a checkout field based on products in the cart
*/
function wc_ninja_remove_checkout_field( $fields ) {
if ( wc_ninja_product_is_in_the_cart() ) {
    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_first_name'] );
}

return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'wc_ninja_remove_checkout_field' );
```

So basically, I think I need to change `unset( $fields['billing']['billing_first_name'] );` to something like `unset( $fields['the_script']['user_script'] );`

but of course it's not working that way. I can't figure out how to access the custom field I created to do this. Been trying for hours without luck!!! Someone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out (finally)

Instead of using the code above to add a new custom field, I changed it to this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields ( $fields ) {

$fields['order']['the_script'] = array (

woocommerce_form_field  ( 'the_script', array(
'type'    =>    'textarea',
'class'   => array('extracheckoutinfo form-row-wide'),
'label'   =>  __('What is the script?'),
'placeholder'  =>   __('You can skin this section if you added the "script" extra to your purchase'),
'required'    =>   true

);

return $fields

}
```

which now allows me to target my custom field like this:

```
unset ($fields['order']['the_script'] );
```